# Spring AOP blocks RestController

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, aop, spring-restcontroller

I try to learn Spring AOP. I've created simple spring boot project in IDEA.

**Service.java**

```
package com.example.demo.service;
//imports..

public interface Service {
    public DataEntity getData();
}
```

**ServiceImpl.java**

```
package com.example.demo.service;
//imports..
@RestController("service")
public class ServiceImpl implements Service {


    @RequestMapping(value="/test", method= RequestMethod.GET)
    public DataEntity getData() {
        DataEntity data = new DataEntity();
        data.setData("SomeString");
        return data;
    }
}
```

**ServiceCallingAspect.java**

```
package com.example.demo.aspects;
//imports..
@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@Component
public class ServiceCallingAspect {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ServiceCallingAspect.class);

    @AfterReturning("execution(public * com.example.demo.service.*.*(..))")
    public void logBeforeRestCall(JoinPoint pjp) throws Throwable {
        log.info(" POST REST call " + pjp);
    }
}
```

**DemoApplication.java**

```
package com.example.demo;
//..

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

So when I try to call my rest service on `http://localhost:8080/test`, I get something like that.

```
{
    "timestamp": 1514109432038,
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/test"
}
```

When I disable my aspect (just comment all annotations in `ServiceCallingAspect.java`) the service works perfectly. Can you show me where I am wrong?

Comment: with the Aspect when you try to reach the url , does it rech the controller? have you debugged this?

Comment: @pvpkiran no, can't reach the controller in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` to `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)`.

```
@Aspect
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass=true)
@Component
public class ServiceCallingAspect {
  .....

}
```

Comment: This works fine, thank you! Can you explain how it works?